# Fabric криво работает

Tags: java, android

Подскажите в чем проблема.

Если я вызываю ошибку типо throw new RuntimeExeption. То в Fabric Появляется лог ошибки.

Но в моем приложении есть throwIndexOutOfBoundsException. Который не крашит приложение, Но выводит в Loge Android Studio об этой ошибке.

Как сделать чтобы Fabric Вообще все ошибки схватывал.А не только те которые крашат приложение с надписью. "Ваше приложение вызвало ошибку"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По умолчанию крашлитика отсылает только не обработанные исключения (те которые валят приложение)

Если вы сам обработали исключение и хотите что бы оно отобразилось в крашлитике, то вам нужно его отправить вручную

```
try {
  myMethodThatThrows();
} catch (Exception e) {
  Crashlytics.logException(e);
}
```

Comment: А можно как то это в AppLication написать? Потому что там кода много где это нужно править.

Comment: Нууууууу... Если ты при перехвате ошибки только выводишь ее в лог, то можно написать статический метод, который будет принимать на вход ошибку и выводить ее в лог и отправлять в крашлитику

Comment: Тоесть если написанно e.printStackTrace();. То исключение обработано и Fabric его не получит?

Comment: Да, не думаю что фабрика может подцепить вызов printStackTrace

Comment: СЛУШАЙТЕ.

Crashlytics.logException(e); Надо добавить перед e.printStackTrace(); или после e.printStackTrace();?

Comment: Не имеет значения, по крайней мере в официальной документации про это ничего не сказано